# jupyter-notebook: does not page scroll when using firefox's Take a ScreenShot. Page scroll gets hidden

Tags: firefox, jupyter-notebook, webpage-screenshot

I am using firefox 66.0.2 (64-bit)
I generally take screenshot of the portion of the webpage very eaily using Take a Screenshot (https://screenshots.firefox.com/)

Now many websites when i want to capture a portion of the webpage, i can page scroll down the web page but with jupyter the page scroll gets hidden when i start take a screenshot from firefox

The image shows page scroll hidden with jupyter

[image: Screenshot_20200304_194229]

I capture lot of things from other websites but their scroll bar does not hide eg:

[image: Screenshot_20200304_194951-1]

Answer (score 2):

I found this is related to css. The scroll bar was not for the entire page it was for a particular div

I tried to customize the css by

```
~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css
#site{
    overflow: unset
}
```

Now i can take the screenshot nicely

Comment: CTRL+Shift+I, Style Editor, just paste this into custom.css there

Comment: I've found this answer doesn't work when using JupyterLab; first it's not clear if it is meant to put everything there in the file `.jupyter/custom/custom.css` or if the first line was just specifying the file? Second it does bring up a new interface upon pressing the screenshot button in Firefox but it forces me to select a region on the **visible** screen--making it not have the intended effect.

Comment: ...using Mac OSX 13.4

Comment: see this link: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5264

Answer (score 0):

I've created simple bookmarklet that unsets overflow and increases height of a few divs in order to enable screenshots that require scrolling the content.
There are two versions - depending on a version of Jupyter Lab (difference in name of one class, 2 occurrences):

Works with class *jp-WindowedPanel-outer*:

```js
javascript:document.querySelectorAll('#jp-main-content-panel, #jp-main-vsplit-panel, #jp-main-split-panel, #jp-main-dock-panel, .lm-Widget.jp-MainAreaWidget.jp-NotebookPanel.jp-Document.jp-Activity.lm-DockPanel-widget, .jp-WindowedPanel-outer.lm-Widget.jp-Notebook.jp-mod-scrollPastEnd.jp-mod-showHiddenCellsButton.jp-NotebookPanel-notebook.jp-mod-editMode, .jp-WindowedPanel-outer.lm-Widget.jp-Notebook.jp-mod-scrollPastEnd.jp-mod-showHiddenCellsButton.jp-NotebookPanel-notebook.jp-mod-commandMode, #jp-WindowedPanel-window ').forEach(e => {
  e.style.height = (parseInt(e.style.height) + 10000) + 'px';
  e.style.overflow = 'unset';
});
document.querySelectorAll('#main, body').forEach(e => {
  e.style.overflow = 'unset';
});
document.getElementById('jp-bottom-panel').style.display = 'none';
void 0;
```

Works with class *jp-WindowedPanel*:

```js
javascript:document.querySelectorAll('#jp-main-content-panel, #jp-main-vsplit-panel, #jp-main-split-panel, #jp-main-dock-panel, .lm-Widget.jp-MainAreaWidget.jp-NotebookPanel.jp-Document.jp-Activity.lm-DockPanel-widget, .jp-WindowedPanel.lm-Widget.jp-Notebook.jp-mod-scrollPastEnd.jp-mod-showHiddenCellsButton.jp-NotebookPanel-notebook.jp-mod-editMode, .jp-WindowedPanel.lm-Widget.jp-Notebook.jp-mod-scrollPastEnd.jp-mod-showHiddenCellsButton.jp-NotebookPanel-notebook.jp-mod-commandMode, #jp-WindowedPanel-window ').forEach(e => {
  e.style.height = (parseInt(e.style.height) + 10000) + 'px';
  e.style.overflow = 'unset';
});
document.querySelectorAll('#main, body').forEach(e => {
  e.style.overflow = 'unset';
});
document.getElementById('jp-bottom-panel').style.display = 'none';
void 0;
```

It can be run as a bookmarklet or through a web console (F12). Works in Firefox, Edge and Chrome (doesn't seem to work with Chrome's area screenshot function - but works with full size and node screenshots and probably with some extensions to capture screenshots).

If the increase of section height is not sufficient, run it again (adds 10000px height with each use).

The CSS selectors can be optimized, perhaps I will do so when bookmarklets will stop working because of some changes to JL.

I did not write code that reverts CSS changes - so you have to reload page to restore normal view.

[image: Demo]